# Returning a Null Object from a Templated Function

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I'm building a templated stack class. When the user calls top, if the stack is empty, I want to return a dummy item. If my stack was of type int, I'd return -1. But, my stack is of type T, so I'm not sure what to return. I want to return a dummy node, but not sure how to initialise it, given that the type isn't declared till main(). What should I send back in return? Do I return nothing? What is the equivalent of nullptr for objects of type T?

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T val;
    Node<T>* nextItem;
    Node(T val_, Node<T>* nextItem_ = nullptr) : val(val_), nextItem(nextItem_) {};
};
```

```
template <typename T> // This top function.
T Stack<T>::top() const {
    if (!isEmpty()) return topItem->val;
    cout << "[WARNING] Stack is empty! Sending dummy object." << endl;
    // return nullptr; // <-- Wrong. What should I return?
}
```

Comment: Throw exception, return `optional<T>`, defaulted T (`T{}`, assuming it exists) customizable traits are possibilities.

Comment: *I want to return a dummy item* I would advise against this.  For something like an `int` there is no valid dummy value.  `-1` is very common integer value and will cause false positives.  I suggest throwing an exception, or using `std::optional` as the return type.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll throw an exception. Thanks!

Comment: You *could* just return a default constructed T `return {};`. But as @Nathan also says, I'd advise against it, because a default constructed object *might* also be *valid*. Exception or `std::optional`.

Answer (score -1):

One way to let the stack class template deal with the problem is to use a helper class that can return a value that is considered invalid for a given type.

```
// Declared but not defined.
template <typename T> struct InvalidValue;


// Use it generically.
template <typename T> // This top function.
T Stack<T>::top() const {
    if (!isEmpty()) return topItem->val;
    cout << "[WARNING] Stack is empty! Sending dummy object." << endl;
    return InvalidValue<T>::get();
}
```

Now define specializations of `InvalidValue` for the types that you care.

```
template <> struct InvalidValue<int>
{
   static int get() { return -1;}
};

template <> struct InvalidValue<char>
{
   static char get() { return '\0';}
};

template <> struct InvalidValue<double>
{
   static double get() { return FLT_MIN;} 
};
```

etc.

Comment: IMHO this is not a good path to take. None of these value are actually invalid.  You can't know generically what an invalid value would be.

Comment: Why not just use `std::optional` or throw an exception?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I understand your POV. It's another tool in the toolbox.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, as I responded to NathanOliver's comment, it's another tool in the toolbox.